# Add tag around selected html

Tags: javascript

I have a contenteditable div and i would like to add some html tags around selection html, after user select the text and click the button..

```html
<div id="richtextbox" contenteditable="true" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow-y: auto;border: 1px solid royalblue;">
    The <span style='color: red;'>quick</span> brown <i>fox</i> jumps over the <span style='background-color: yellow;'>lazy</span> dog.
</div>
```

The quick brown *fox* jumps over the lazy dog.

I want on user highlight text "quick brown fox jumps", I will get html string

```
quick</span> brown <i>fox</i> jumps
```

and add tag "b" to start selection and "/b" to end selection, result:

```
<b>quick</span> brown <i>fox</i> jumps</b>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show what structure do you want to have after the click?

Comment: hi @balzacLeGeek, I did edit question

Comment: "quick brown fox jumps"

Comment: Why not use WYSIWYG ready plugins?

Comment: I can't use plugin, so I am looking for a way to do it myself

Comment: can you please explain what your problem is, what you tried and then what your expected answer should be - I dont understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I would put an id to your span, to be able to access the object with `getElementById()` and use the innerHtml property:

the html

```html
<span id="my-id" style='color: red;'>quick</span> brown <i>fox</i> jumps over the <span style='background-color: yellow;'>lazy</span>
```

the function to surround with a markup

```js
function surroundWithMarkup(str, markup) {
  return `<${markup}>${str}</${markup}>`
}
```

the call to the method

```js
// Could be inside an event like onclick for example
const mySpan = document.getElementById('my-id')
mySpan.innertHTML = surroundWithMarkup(mySpan.innertHTML, 'b') // if you want the bold markup
```

Comment: Can't use your solution, because I want add tag around to element highlight by user.
ex: user highlight text by mouse -> click button to set bold/italic/color to highlight text

Comment: Find a way to retrieve the currently selected text, then pass it to the function, then combine innerHTML with str.replace() function and the behaviour wanted should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery `.wrap`

```
$( ".inner" ).wrap("<div class='new'></div>")
```

[JQuery .wrap](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)